# How to fix the footer to scroll when the block content increases?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem, my English is not good, but I try to describe my problem completely!

There is currently a window. The screen to be implemented is that the footer should be fixed at the bottom of the container, and should not move down as the content of the white block increases. Then, when the content of the white block is too much, the entire window will not change. Large, and the white block content can be scrolled to view other options.

[`My example`](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/yLbXMKB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I could understand, you need to fix footer.You just need to uncomment your commented code of `footer` and change `position:fixed` Or `position: sticky;` from `position: absolute`
i.e Your footer code of `CSS` would be;

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
 //position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color: #f77331;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  padding:10px;
  z-index:9000;
  .btn{
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:20px;
  }
}
```

Then if your content hides due to `fixed` position of footer you can use margin for that content.Hope this would solve your problem.